# Ping on workout from connected device to Google Fit

Tags: google-fit

Reading through the documentation for Google fit it seams that you have to poll for workouts regularly to get new workouts. According to the documentation to get a workout you have to list it with a get call [source](https://developers.google.com/fit/faq#how_do_i_read_data_written_to_the_platform_by_other_apps_or_devices). Is there another way than polling? It would be wonderful to get some ping every time a workout is done instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up polling it, as it looks like that is the only way to do it unfortunately.